# How can I read data from a table in Microsoft Azure Mobile Services and put it in my application?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I am using Xamarin Studio and Microsoft Azure Mobile Services. I am trying to read data I put into a table in Microsoft Azure Mobile Service and display it in my application. I followed all of the tutorials on the Azure website but I cant seem to find how to just get data from a table. I want to display to the User what they entered into the table.

Here is my code for entering data into the table:

```
//this just sets up the connection and table
private static readonly MobileServiceClient MobileService = 
        new MobileServiceClient (UsersConstants.ApplicationURL, UsersConstants.ApplicationKey);
private readonly IMobileServiceTable<UsersTable> usersTable = MobileService.GetTable<UsersTable>();

//this creates a new item 
var NewItem = new UsersTable ();
NewItem.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
NewItem.Email = EmailTextBox.Text;
NewItem.Password = PasswordTextBox.Text;

//this inserts the item into the table I have set up
usersTable.InsertAsync(NewItem);
```

I then switch to another view in my application (its an iOS application) and I want to get this data from the table and put it in to my application. I have been looking around but I haven't found how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (exact syntax may need tweaking)

```
async private void GetUsers() {

    var users = await usersTable.Where (u => u.Name == "Bob").ToListAsync();

}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error saying "The _await_ operator can only be used when its containing method is marked with the _async_ modifier."

Comment: Well, then add an async modifier to your method.  See my edit

Comment: Oh thats simple, one last question. How would I print out what it returned?

Comment: If you just want to check the output, you can use Console.Writeline to write it to the log.  If you want to display it in your UI, you would need to create a view and pass the data to it.  It's hard to give a concrete answer, it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I use Console.Writeline, it prints out "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.QueryResultList`1[Bumper_IOS.UsersTable]." How do I get an actual result?

Comment: This is basic C#.  Your result is a collection, so you need to iterate through the collection and print each one.  Something like foreach(var x in users) { Console.Writeline(x.Name); }