# Azure Mobile Services : Exception on InsertAsync

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to do an insert to a windows Azure mobile service db from a Xamarin applicaiton. the insert works fine. but i get the following exception.

i see there are some issues related to the below link looks related to this. but still cannot get it working for me.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1797

```
Exception=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at xPlatAuction.Backend.Controllers.BidController.<PostBid>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext(), Id=855e229d-5653-45c3-9e9a-178a3aea5244, Category='App.Filters'
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception logs you mentioned, it might have missed up some I/P parameters which throws NULL reference, the Insert sync method was working fine previously.

You have not mentioned about the inputs you gave, please find some areas where the error :

1. As you are developing an application tackling cross platform (Using Xamarin i.e. you may be developing Android or IOS or Windows App & Interacting with Azure Mobile Services). So there may be [an issue with the object inputs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a47c9b11-81d0-4f19-8090-133250d3fb4b/problem-insertasync-xamarin-azure-mobile-service?forum=azuremobile)
2. Input URL would [have been wrongly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346847/xamarin-monoandroid-azure-mobile-service-insertasync). You may use [following reference](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/having-fun-with-azure-mobile-services-integrating-with-windows-8/) too (this Insert sync method was working fine previously too).

You can also take a look at following question:

[How can I read data from a table in Microsoft Azure Mobile Services and put it in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853593/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-table-in-microsoft-azure-mobile-services-and-put-it-i)